# No results in Django Haystack search

Tags: django, search-engine, django-haystack, whoosh

I've read the getting started documentation and several other examples on the web.
And this is what my search_indexes.py looks like:

```
from haystack.indexes import *
from haystack import site
from models import Entry

class EntryIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True)
    headline = CharField(model_attr='headline')
    subheadline = CharField(model_attr='subheadline')
    category = CharField(model_attr='category__name')

    author = CharField(model_attr='get_author')
    email = CharField(model_attr='get_email')

    tags = CharField(model_attr='tags')

    content = CharField(model_attr='content')

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Entry.objects.exclude(dt_published=None).order_by('-is_featured', '-dt_published', '-dt_written', 'headline')

site.register(Entry, EntryIndex)
```

But when I search, I get no results. Strangely though if I use the search phrase 'a' or any other single letter, 
I get what looks like every single entry in the damn thing.

Anyway... It looks to me like the search engine isn't looking in any of the fields. :/

Anything below this line is less relevant (it works, trust me):

---

My view:

```
from haystack.views import SearchView

class CustomSearchView(SearchView):
    def __name__(self):
        return "CustomSearchView"

    def extra_context(self):
        return common(self.request)

def search(request):
    return CustomSearchView(template='news/search_results.html')(request)
```

And search_results.html:

```
{% extends "content.html" %}
{% load tagging_tags %}
{% load highlight %}


{% block title %}Viðskiptablaðið - Leitarniðurstöður{% endblock %}

{% block left_content %}

<h2>Search</h2>

<form method="get">
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Search">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    {% if query %}
        <h3>Results</h3>

        {% for result in page.object_list %}
            {% highlight result.summary with request.GET.q %}
            {% highlight result.object.headline with request.GET.q %}
            <p>
                <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ result.object.headline }}</a>
            </p>
        {% empty %}
            <p>No results found.</p>
        {% endfor %}

        {% if page.has_previous or page.has_next %}
            <div>
                {% if page.has_previous %}<a href="?q={{ query }}&amp;page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">{% endif %}&laquo; Previous{% if page.has_previous %}</a>{% endif %}
                |
                {% if page.has_next %}<a href="?q={{ query }}&amp;page={{ page.next_page_number }}">{% endif %}Next &raquo;{% if page.has_next %}</a>{% endif %}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        {# Show some example queries to run, maybe query syntax, something else? #}
    {% endif %}
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What search engine are you using? If it's Solr for example,  have you configured it properly to use those fields?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ok, it is in the documentation but I feel it's not clear enough.

What you have to do is to declare somehow the data to be searched (i thought that was the whole point of:

```
headline = CharField(model_attr='headline')
subheadline = CharField(model_attr='subheadline')
```

etc...)

ok, enough crying.

All you have to do is

```
text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
```

and then make a template, in my case:

search/indexes/news/entry_text.txt

```
{{ object.headline }}
{{ object.subheadline }}
{{ object.get_author }}
{{ object.get_email }}
{{ object.category.name }}
{{ object.tags }}
{{ object.content }}
```

Beautiul, it works.